# Control a LED flashlight from drone's power port

Tags: led, circuit-design, drone

My drone has a switchable power port to control a searchlight/loudspeaker accessory.

The searchlight does not really meet the mission profile as well as puts a significant drain on the the drone's battery.

A LED flashlight is better suited to meet mission requirements. The light pattern is better and the flashlight has independent power source.

While I could power the flashlight directly from the accessory port, this would still tax the drone's battery though at a significantly lower rate.

I would like to turn the flashlight on and off during flight by using the drone's accessory port control without placing a continuous load on the battery. The drone is powered by a pair of 26 V batteries wired in parallel.

Comment: Even a power mosfet will have a slight continuous drain.  Probably acceptable though.

Comment: What is the voltage of the accessory port?

Comment: The spec sheet for my searchlight/loudspeaker says input voltage is 24V.